# How to actualize entity in Spring JPA? Actualize or create new one?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm wondering what is best practice to update JPA entity in Spring project - update original entity or create new? I see these two approaches:

1. Use original - Actualize necessary fields in original entity and save this updated entity back to the repository.
2. Use copy - manually create new instance of entity, set all field from original entity (+ updated fields) into new entity and save the entity back to the repository.

What approach do you use / is recommended? And why?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to updating, the standard way would be to retrieve the entity reference(read below) and make changes within a transactional method:

```
private JpaRepository repo;

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void performChanges(Integer id){
     Entity e = repo.getOne(id);

     // alter the entity object
}
```

Few things regarding the example:

- You would want to use the `getOne` method of `JpaRepository` as much as possible as it is in general faster than the `findOne` of the `CrudRepository`. The only trick is that you have to be sure that entity actually exists in the database with the given id. Otherwise you would get an exception. This does not occur regarding the `findOne` method so you would need to make that decision regarding each transactional method which alters a single entity within your application.
- You do not need to trigger any `persist` or `save` methods on the `EntityManager` as the changes will be automatically flushed when the transaction is commited.. and that is on method return.

Regarding your second option, I dont think thats much of a use as you would need to get the data using above method anyway. If you intend to use that entity outside of the transaction, then again you could use the one retrieved from the exmaple above and then perform `merge` once it is again needed within the transactional context and thus Persistence Provider.

Answer (score 0):

Getting an entity and then just updating that entity is the easiest way to do that. Also this is faster than a creation of a copy since `EntityManager` manages an entity and know that managed entity already exists in DB (so no need to execute additional query).

Anyway, there is third and the fastest approach: using `executeUpdate` on `Query` object.

```
entityManager
    .createQuery("update EntityName set fieldName = :fieldName where id = :id")
    .setParameter("fieldName", "test")
    .setParameter("id", id)
    .executeUpdate();
```

It is faster due to bypassing the persistent context

Comment: You just have to make sure that the execute is within its own transaction or that its the first call in the transactional method